# Setting up inequalities is proving difficult

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given $$(a+b)^2\leq4$$
$$(a-b)^2\leq4$$

Is this true?

$$2(a+b)^2+2(a-b)^2-b^2\leq16$$

The problem I need to solve is to find the maximum value of $(4a^2+3b^2)$ Please help.

Comment: Yes.  $(a+b)^2 \le 4; (a-b)^2 \le 4;$ and $b^2 \ge 0$ so $2(a+b)^2 + 2(a-b)^2 \le 2*4 + 2*4 = 16$.  And $2(a+b)^2 + 2(a-b)^2 - b^2 \le 2(a+b)^2 + 2(a-b)^2 \le 16$.

Comment: @fleablood So it's true because $b^2\geq0$ right?

Answer (score 1):

$(a+b)^2 \le 4$ so $2(a+b)^2 \le 8$.

$(a-b)^2 \le 4$ so $2(a-b)^2 \le 8$.

So $2(a+b)^2 + 2(a+b)^2 \le 8+8 = 16$.

And $b^2 \ge 0$ so

$2(a+b)^2 + 2(a+b)^2-b^2 \le 2(a+b)^2 + 2(a+b)^2 \le 16$.

$16 \ge 2(a+b)^2 + 2(a+b)^2-b^2 = 2(a^2 + 2ab +b^2) + 2(a^2 -2ab + b^2) -b^2 = 4a^2 + 3b^2$.  So $16$ is a potential maximum.  But we don't know if it is an achievable maximum.

But if $(a+b)^2 = 4$ its maximum; and $(a -b)^2=4$ its maximum; and $b^2 = 0$; it's minimum then $4a^2 + 3b^2$ will meet its maximum of $16$.

$b^2 = 0 \implies b=0$ and so $(a+b)^2 = a^2 = (a-b)^2 =4$ which implies $a=\pm 2$ allow $4a^2 + 3b^2$ to equal a maximum possible value of $16$

Comment: Um.... I don't understand the question in the comment at all.  If $|a + c - c| = 2$ then $|a + 0| = |a| = 2$ and $a = \pm 2$.  $c$ can anything at all in the world but $|a + c| = |c \pm 2|$ which usually isn't equal to $|c|$ unless... oh, I see.  You worded your question wrong.  If $|a+c -c| = 2$ *and* you are *also* given that $|a+c| = |c|$ then you can conclude that $|c| = 1$. $|a +  c - c| =|a|$.  And $|a+c|=|c|$ means $a +c = \pm c$ means $a = \pm c - c = -2c$ or $0$.  Since we know $|a| = 2$ we know $a\ne 0$. so $a = -2c = \pm 2$ so $c = \pm 1$.  But |a+c-c|=2 by itself doesn't tell us.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks. I kinda deleted the comment. But thanks for answering, its quite helpful. Supplemented my 
understanding